# Typescript - exportar tipos de submodulo

Tags: typescript, npm, type

estoy haciendo un paquete que usa un paquete npm, este paquete npm contiene unos tipos que debería publicar mi paquete para quien lo usa poder utilizarlos, pero no encuentro la manera de conseguirlo...

Alguien ha hecho algo similar?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres generar los tipos para tus modelos puedes añadir el atributo `declaration: true` en tu fichero `tsconfig.json`. Y en el build se generaran los tipos automáticamente.

```
compilerOptions: {
  declaration: true,
  // declarationDir para definir el fichero de salida de los tipos. Es opcional
}
```

[Aquí](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) tienes todos las opciones del fichero de configuración.